# tkinter two combobox always getting the same value

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a GUI app, I am at an early stage.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Test")
        self.geometry("760x250")
        self.inter_sources = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        self.inter_destinations = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        self.source_options = ttk.Combobox(self, state="readonly", width=40,
                                           values=self.inter_sources, textvariable=self.inter_sources)
        self.destination_options = ttk.Combobox(self, state="readonly", width=40,
                                                values=self.inter_destinations, textvariable=self.inter_destinations)

    def place_options(self):
        self.source_options.place(x=10, y=40)
        self.source_options.set(self.inter_sources[0])
        self.destination_options.place(x=10, y=80)
        self.destination_options.set(self.inter_destinations[0])


x = App()
x.place_options()
x.mainloop()
```

For some reason whenever any of the `source_options` or `destination_options` change value, the other will take the same value, I am not sure if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong.
What I want is that the normal operation happens where if one changes the other does not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `textvariable=` option has to be a `StringVar` or similar Tkinter var object; passing the same list as the `values=` option makes no sense.

Comment: @jasonharper it is not the same list though, I haven't declared 1 variable and assigned it to both

Comment: it makes no sense to pass a list as a value to the `textvariable` option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textvariable=` is not for assigning list with all values.

It is for assigning `StringVar()` (or similar objects) to get or set selected value in `Combobox`. And tkinter uses string with ID to recognize assigned `StringVar`.

When you use the same list then it convert to the same string and both `Combobox` get the same ID (and probably create automatically `StringVar` for this ID - but I can't confirm it. `tkinter` runs all as code in language`tk` which I don't use).
And when you change selection in one `Combobox` then it changes value in `StringVar` which automatically changes selection in all `Combobox` which use the same ID.

You should create two `StringVar`s and assign to different `Combobox`s

```
self.inter_sources = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
self.inter_destinations = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

self.selected_source = tk.StringVar(self)
self.selected_destination = tk.StringVar(self)

self.source_options = ttk.Combobox(self, state="readonly", width=40,
                                   values=self.inter_sources,
                                   textvariable=self.selected_source
                                   )

self.destination_options = ttk.Combobox(self, state="readonly", width=40,
                                        values=self.inter_destinations,
                                        textvariable=self.selected_destination
                                        )
```

---

But if you want only get value from `Combobox` then you don't need `textvariable` because you may get it directly from `Combobox`

Example code with button which runs code to get vlaues from all `Combobox`

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Test")
        self.geometry("760x250")
        
        self.inter_sources = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        self.inter_destinations = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        
        self.selected_source = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.selected_destination = tk.StringVar(self)
        
        self.source_options = ttk.Combobox(self, state="readonly", width=40,
                                           values=self.inter_sources,
                                           textvariable=self.selected_source
                                           )
        
        self.destination_options = ttk.Combobox(self, state="readonly", width=40,
                                                values=self.inter_destinations,
                                                textvariable=self.selected_destination
                                                )
     
        tk.Button(self, text='Check', command=self.on_press).pack()
        
    def on_press(self):
        print('selected_source:', self.selected_source.get())
        print('source_options :', self.source_options.get())
        print('selected_destination:', self.selected_destination.get())
        print('destination_options :', self.destination_options.get())

    def place_options(self):
        self.source_options.place(x=10, y=40)
        self.source_options.set(self.inter_sources[0])
        self.destination_options.place(x=10, y=80)
        self.destination_options.set(self.inter_destinations[0])


x = App()
x.place_options()
x.mainloop()
```